# How to add a torrent to a running rtorrent download?

Tags: configuration, bittorrent, rtorrent

So there is a directory full of torrent files:

```
debian.iso.torrent
fedora.iso.torrent
```

I can start downloading them with a:

```
rtorrent *.torrent
```

command, when the working directory is the same where the torrents are.

But. Every time when I start rtorrent in this way it calculates all the hashes..it takes looong time do to that and it's a cpu intensive thing.

Are there any methods to avoid this? (other console-based torrent client? or a feature to add a single torrent when already downloading a torrent without calculating all the torrent's hashes?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up a "session directory" so that some data is stored and, when you exit rtorrent cleanly, you can open it without going through the hashing.

According to the manpage, this can be done using the `-s path` option, so `-s ~/torrentdir` would use that as session directory. But you probably want to set this through `~/.rtorrent.rc` so that you don't have to specify it all the time.

(Sorry for the lack of a working example, I don't have a computer with `rtorrent` set up near me right now.)

Comment: The configuration file is `~/.rtorrent.rc`, not `~/.rtorrentrc`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a single `.torrent` while running `rtorrent` - just hit `Bksp` and type the path to the torrent and hit `Enter`. It is possible mess around with the `hash*` settings in `.rtorrent.rc` to change values for how often hash calculations should be made etc. but be careful if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the files are correct and don't want to calculate the hash, you need to add fast resume data. The [relevant rTorrent wiki](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentCommonTasks#Addingfastresumedatatotorrentfiles) page documents how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Watch a directory for new torrents
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,load_start=/var/torrents/todo/*.torrent

# actions
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.set_directory=/var/torrents/done/;execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,/var/torrents/done/"
```

now just put the file in /var/torrents/todo/
when it is done, it will get moved to /var/torrents/done

Comment: How does this avoid the hash check?

Comment: Well, his title asks how to do this.